# UITextField validation in UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

I have a `UIAlertController` with a `UITextField`, a Cancel and OK buttons. Now, the OK button is initially disabled, and when the User type something it gets enabled.

My goal is however, that the OK button should be enabled every time, and the validation performed after the User hits OK. If the User didn't type anything then the `UIAlertController` should not disappear but inform the User to type something.

How can I achieve this?

Thank You,

Comment: "If the User didn't type anything then the UIAlertController should not disappear but inform the User to type something" How? You can't use an alert to inform the user; you're already _in_ an alert. What's your plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do what you describe is not to use an alert at all. Use a presented view controller that *looks* like an alert. Now you are in total charge of the view, and modify its interface however you like, such as adding a label that tells the user to fill out the text field.

Comment: I figured this also. I hoped there is a built in mechanism for this in `UIAlertController`. Thanks.